# How to exlude some model fields in JSON in GET-Method?

Tags: c#, json, .net, api

I'm writing my first WEB-Api using ASP.NET Core. When I return items as JSON, there is such field as PhotoID which I don't wanna include in JSON-response. How can i realise it?

```
    [HttpGet("{type}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetItems(int page, int count, string type)
    {
        var itemsCount = _context.ClothesItems.Where(i => i.Type == type).Count();
        var amountToSkip = page == 1 ? 0 : page * count;
        var amountToTake = count - amountToSkip;

        if (amountToSkip >= itemsCount || count > amountToTake) 
            return BadRequest("The number of item need to take is out of range!");

        var clothesItems = await _context.ClothesItems.Where(i=> i.Type==type)
                                                      .Include("Photos")
                                                      .Skip(amountToSkip)
                                                      .Take(amountToTake)
                                                      .ToListAsync();

        var responsesStatusCode = Response.StatusCode;

        var result = new
        {
            items = clothesItems,
            total = itemsCount,
            statusCode = responsesStatusCode,
        };

        return new JsonResult(result);
    }
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5wYq.jpg - json

Comment: Please don't add the JSON response but include it as "code" sample in the post so that the post is clearer and easier to answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute in the photos model to prevent it from being de serialised. But this will also prevent this value from being captured from a request, if you are planning to use the same model as a request body.

Consider having a look at this for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-5-0